# Which one has higher entropy?

Tags: c++, random

So let's say you have to choose randomly between 9 Numbers with 
`rand() % 9 +1` where each number corresponds to a different object

Is it the same as choosing randomly by first doing `rand() % 3 +1` where
each number corresponds to 3 different rows (which contain 3 different objects)
and then using `rand() % 3 +1` again to choose the objects

I mean do both methods have the same distribution in results?

Hope you get what I'm saying. Sorry for my english.

Comment: Using the mod trick does not always result in an fair distribution. `rand()` is notoriously poorly implemented on many compilers. If you are seriously interested in the properties of your random numbers, use C++11 random or a decent library.

Comment: Definitely don't use modulo operator. It's quite common for `rand() % 2` to yield an regular sequence like [ 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1…]

Comment: This feels more like a statistics question than a programming one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, your entropy is directly related to your RNG. *All* versions of `rand()` have a distressingly low entropy. Get a better RNG.

No matter what you do, though, in order to maintain entropy you must also refrain from biasing your results, and, as noted already, modulo does just that. (CF the Pigeonhole principle.) Better to just toss out-of-range values until you get one in range. [The comp.lang.c FAQ list has an answer that touches this](http://c-faq.com/lib/randrange.html).

To answer your specific question, there are two parts:

1) Because of the remainder operation, the two are not equivalently biased. But... assuming you properly eliminate that bias...

2) Two consecutive calls to the same PRNG are not independent, so while the bits in each call are randomly-distributed, their concatenation does not necessarily have the same entropy as a single call. [See Chris Peikert's answer on crypto.stackexchange.com](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/18591/entropy-of-two-concatenated-random-values/18593#18593).

[edit] So, to answer your question, the first.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Alright I got it! Thanks for the answer, the link was very helpful.